# how configure jwebsockets with my existing application running on tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, websocket

I am trying to use Jwebsockets with my existing project. I have done the configuration with my Tomcat Apache server and able to run all the demo application using

```
  http://localhost:8080/jWebSocketAppSrvDemo-1.0/
```

Its working fine Jwebsocket server is running fine on my machine.

Now I don't know what to do to integrate it with my exiting application how I  can send the messages to jwebsockets server and receive messages from server. I am new to this kind of technology. I tried the tutorial mentioned on website but I am not able do that like in first jWebSocket "Hello World" tutorial I don't know where I set the IURL,gUsername,IPassword. Same with the next tutorial I don't know where I can get WebSocketTokenListener interface. I have added jWebSocketServer-Bundle-1.0.jar file to my lib folder. I feel that tutorial is not step by step tutorial.

Can anyone suggest how I can integrate it with my application if I want to post and reply some message on my website.

Is this right to use jWebsockets with the java application? I am using spring and springMVC framework with Apache Tomcate on Ubuntu

Comment: did you manage to find solution? I have same problem but can't find any real solution on net.